# kbhit and multiple calls on function

Tags: c, kbhit

While making a asteroid shooter, I came around using `_kbhit()` and `kbhit()`. I'm no expert, but here is the problem I think I'm having:

```
int run = 1;

int main() {
    while(run){
        if(GetUserInput() == 2)
            printf("W");
        if(GetUserInput() == 1)
            printf("S");
        Sleep(50);
    }
}

int GetUserInput(){
    if(kbhit()){
        char c = _getch();
        if(c == 's')
            return 2;
        if(c == 'w')
            return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;*

}
```

So, what I think is happening, it does the first check on `GetUserInput()`, and because of the nature of `getch()`, the keyboard is read from the buffer and discarded? Anyways, I store the value in `c` and should return appropriately. But it only does the first check. Is it because there is no more input on the buffer after the first check (in the `main()` function)?

Comment: What do you mean by "first check"? You can use the `if(_kbhit())` / `_getch()` combination in a loop to read multiple characters if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to read once for every key you're interested in with this code:

```
if(GetUserInput() == 2)
    printf("W");
if(GetUserInput() == 1)
    printf("S");
```

For example, I press 'S', you read the key, check if the return value is 2 and it is not. Then you try to read another key, but I haven't pressed one, so the second check for 'S' also fails.

To fix this you need to perform all of your tests on the value you get from `GetUserInput()`.

```
int val = GetUserInput();
if(val == 2)
    printf("W");
else if(val == 1)
    printf("S");
```

You don't need to use else if, but once you've found a match it makes no sense to keep checking if all of your checks are mutually exclusive.  You might consider using a switch statement and an enum instead of hardcoded magic values, or even return the key value directly if one is pressed and a sentinel value like 0 that won't match any of the keys you're interested in.

Here is a complete example that works for me:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int GetUserInput()
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        char c = _getch();
        switch (c)
        {
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            return 2;

        case 'w':
        case 'W':
            return 1;

        case 'x':
        case 'X':
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        int c = GetUserInput();
        switch (c)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("W");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("S");
            break;
        case -1:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but it does the same thing, passes the W ant not the S

Comment: I added a complete example that works correctly for me. It prints W or S if you press those keys and exits if you press X.